# An Error has Occurred with custom entity in Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I have several custom entities that I've defined for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0.  Half of them work, the other half do not.  When I navigate to them, all I see is 'An error has occurred.'

Do people have any suggestions as to a) how I can get this more specific and b) why some entities might show a list of data while others just show 'an error has occurred'?

Thanks, I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

We will need to see the stack trace before we can give any more specific help.

[And to do that you will need to enable tracing.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490)